# Function parameter duplicating another parameter's pointer address accidently?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, pointers, managed-c++

Today I've run across a rather strange error. Essentially what is happening is inside the function `foo` the first parameter is being set to the pointer value of the pointer `crosssegments`. So say `crosssegments` is location at 0x0045 then `iMeaninglessdata` will be set at 0x0045. If I take out `iMeaninglessData` and simply have `o1` as the first parameter than `o1` will be equal to 0x0045. If I pause the debugger before the function is called `iMeaningless` data and `crosssegments` have different pointer addresses.

```
void Foo(int *iMeaninglessData, handle o1, handle o2, handle o3, int iHeight, int iProfileHeight, handle o4, std::vector<object> * crossSegments, int *iProfileArray)
{
    //...code
}
```

Here is how I am calling the function:

```
std::vector<FormSummary> * crossSegmentsTop = new std::vector<FormSummary>();
int iZero = 0;
Foo(&iZero, o1, o2, o3, 10, 50, o4, crossSegmentsTop, iProfileArray);
```

I'm very confused as to how this could be happening. Do you think something could be happening to the stack?

Thank you,

- Alikar

Comment: Can you show the code inside Foo?

Comment: You're probably violating the Single Definition Rule.

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean and full rebuild of your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a bug in the visual studio 2008 debugger when used with release mode versus debug mode. I'm generating the PDB file, but apparently until you use the value, such as in a command window, it doesn't correctly locate the pointer for the variable.

Comment: That's not a bug; that's an artifact of the optimization process.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is going on with the optimization process to cause that? Is there a flag I can turn off or on to adjust that?

Comment: Optimization includes potentially removing stack space for local variables. So no, not without disabling optimizations.

Comment: Actually that is good to know. I can simply turn off optimizations while I debug with release code.